# how define z-index of some popup windows?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup, window

i have 4 popup windows -> width:100% and height:100%
is there a way to define z-index of those popup windows?
i want to show their parent at top of it's childs!
how can i do that?

two of my popup windows are like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('http://www.MyPoPup1.com', '_blank', 'location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,toolbar=no');
    window.open('http://www.MyPoPup2.com', '_blank', '');
</script>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Focus()` method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newWin = window.open(...); 
window.focus(); // Will cause parent window to be ON TOP of child window
</script>
```

Comment: Try using window.focus() for the parent window.